# How to make double click instead of single click to open file in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

It is an drag and drop file upload in angular. Two ways I can upload files either drag and drop or click the icon and select and upload the file.

Here drag and drop is not an issue. But If i click the plus icon it will open finder ( drive in windows) and i can select any image or file to upload.

Whenever I will click on plus icon it is opening the finder. But I want to open the finder only when i will double click on the icon. If single click it should not allow to open the finder.

Please find the below stackblitz example for the file upload.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file)

```
<input-file placeholder="Pictures"
            fileAccept="image/*" 
            fileLimit="2"  
            (dblclick)="openFolder()"></input-file>
```

Can anyone please help me to do this?

Comment: very weird you would want double click... only way around it would be to capture click and cancel it.

Comment: If I click second time it will take count as 2. But it is not an double click. So it wont work. I want to open folder on double click. Any other way is there?

Answer (score 0):

//You can use a variable "yet". If true, make a (click) else preventDefault

```
<input-file (click)="click($event)" (dblclick)="openFolder($event)" 
         placeholder="Drop files below!">
</input-file>
```

In yout .ts

```
  yet:boolean=false; //A variable
  openFolder($event)
  {
    //create a mouseEvent 
    let event = new MouseEvent('click',{
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
    this.yet=true;  //equal variable to true
    var cancelled = !$event.target.dispatchEvent(event);
     this.yet=false;  //return the value to false
  }
  click($event)
  {
    if (!this.yet) //If variable is false
    {
      $event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick hack would be to just check the timing of the click events:

```
<input-file fileAccept="image/*" fileLimit="2" placeholder="Pictures" (click)="openFolder()"></input-file>
```

.

```
private lastClick: number

openFolder () {
    const now = Date.now()

    // replace 1000 with whatever maximum interval you want to count as a double click
    if (now - this.lastClick < 1000) {
        // open the folder
    } else {
        this.lastClick = now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store button state on button's `dataset` object:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  button;

  click(ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      !this.button && (this.button = ev.target);
      if (!this.button.dataset.allowClick) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        delete this.button.dataset.allowClick;
      }
    }
  }

  dblclick(ev) {
    this.button.dataset.allowClick = true;
    this.button.click();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input-file (click)="click($event)" 
            (dblclick)="dblclick($event)"
            placeholder="Drop files below!"></input-file>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file-n2flxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)